# Query in stored procedure does not use primary index and very slow

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm attempting to use a stored procedure.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE cuiTitle(IN cui_in CHAR(8))
BEGIN
    EXPLAIN SELECT str FROM MRCONSO
        WHERE cui = cui_in
        AND ts = 'P' 
        AND stt = 'PF' 
        AND ispref = 'Y' 
        LIMIT 1;
END //
CALL cuiTitle('C0269037');
```

The query is very slow. it does a fully scan instead of using the primary index.

```
id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE  MRCONSO NULL    ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    5814290 0.10    Using where
```

If querying directly or using hardcoded value instead of parameter, the query is very fast and uses the primary key.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE cuiTitle(IN cui_in CHAR(8))
BEGIN
    EXPLAIN SELECT str FROM MRCONSO
        WHERE cui = 'C0269037'
        AND ts = 'P' 
        AND stt = 'PF' 
        AND ispref = 'Y' 
        LIMIT 1;
END //
CALL cuiTitle('C0269037');
```

its "explain":

```
id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE  MRCONSO NULL    ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 24  const   10  0.50    Using where
```

Why is it? how can I make the stored procedure use the primary key?
I've tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/21687188/218677 recommendation but with no success..

UPDATE:
I don't know if the makes a difference, but it primary key is:
PRIMARY KEY (`CUI`,`AUI`),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out https://stackoverflow.com/a/21687188/218677  was correct.
I've got the wrong char set

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE cuiTitle(IN cui_in CHAR(8))
BEGIN
    EXPLAIN SELECT str FROM MRCONSO
 FORCE INDEX (PRIMARY)
        WHERE cui = convert(cui_in using utf8)
        AND ts = 'P' 
        AND stt = 'PF' 
        AND ispref = 'Y' 
        LIMIT 1;
END //
```

Works

Answer (score 0):

There are possibilitys to hint mysql to use an index as far as i can see without seeing your table, that you don't have a **combined index** for (cui , ts, stt,ispref), which you could also use .

```
  SELECT str FROM MRCONSO
  USE INDEX (PRIMARY)
        WHERE cui = cui_in
        AND ts = 'P' 
        AND stt = 'PF' 
        AND ispref = 'Y' 
        LIMIT 1;
```

And

```
  SELECT str FROM MRCONSO
  FORCE INDEX (PRIMARY)
        WHERE cui = cui_in
        AND ts = 'P' 
        AND stt = 'PF' 
        AND ispref = 'Y' 
        LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Also use the combined index mentioned in the answer.